# What statue is this in Athens near the Acropolis?

Tags: identify-this, greece, athens

Does anyone know who this statue is of?

https://goo.gl/maps/29giAzrQHrm

[image]

I passed it at night and didn't get a good chance to read it carefully, but I thought I saw something on it about Bolivia or something.

Comment: I love how the statue’s face is pixelated =D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a statue of [General Yannis Makriyannis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yannis_Makriyannis). The location is on the intersection of Dionysiou Areopagitou and Vyronos Streets.

[image: General Yannis Makriyannis]

The inscription on the base of the statue mentions the General's name and years of life, sprayed over by some vandals.

[image]

Source: [Waymarking.com](http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/WMPFKT_Yannis_Makriyannis_Athens_Greece)